# How to find recurrence relation from a given recursive function

Tags: algorithm, recursion, recurrence

I'm going through old exam set for my data structures & algorithm course and can't seem to figure out how to solve this problem.

**Question (d)** Find a recurrence relation for the number of multiplications performed by the following recursive method:

```
static int f(int N)
   {
       if (N > 1) return 2*f(N - 1);
       else return 3;
   }
```

**Answer:** `T(N) = T(N − 1) + 1`

I don't fully understand how does this relation find the number of multiplications?

```
T(2) = T(2 - 1) + 1 = 2
```

```
T(3) = T(3 - 1) + 1 = 3
```

I tried plugging 2 and 3 in the relation but I still don't see how that is the number of multiplications. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `f(N)` you have one more recursive call than for `f(N-1)`, so one more multiplication, thus

```
T(N) = T(N-1) + 1
```

with base case `T(1) = 0`.